# Does the word " answerers " exist?

Tags: word-usage

I am new to this site.While reading a mail ,I came across this phrase.

> " askers asking questions, answerers answering "

While I was typing I was prompted with the following options ,none of which suite to my current question.

- answers
- answered
- answer

And I quote from Collins dictionary which says,

> answer 
>   Word forms: plural, 3rd person singular present tense answers  , present participle answering  , past tense, past participle answered.

Similarly I quote from Cambridge dictionary,

> answer noun :reaction

My question is does the word "**answerers**" exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it exists.

Answer = the "result" of a question

Answer**er** = the person (or robot?!) providing an answer

[**Answerers**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/answerer) = plural of answerer

Note that it is informal and rarely used.

Comment: but just because a word exists doesn't mean it should be used

Comment: @WendyG: true. On the other hand, if it exists and if it fits, why not. Especially if it is not "4-lettered".

Comment: because it is just a horrible word to say

Comment: Again, you might be correct. But there are more horrible words, and yet people use them :(